# Confusion about passing instance variables to redirect_to method. As seen in Rails Guides

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am studying the ruby on rails guides namely, the "layouts and rendering" topic at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

I am confused about passing an instance variable to a `redirect_to` method. How is this possible? I thought `redirect_to` would be relevant for redirecting to another webpage or a url.

In the examples given on the guide it says the following:

> **2.2.2 Rendering an Action’s View**
>
> If you want to render the view that corresponds to a different action
>   within the same template, you can use render with the name of the
>   view:
>
> ```
> def update
>   @book = Book.find(params[:id])
>   if @book.update_attributes(params[:book])
>     redirect_to(@book)
>   else
>     render "edit"
>   end
> end
> ```

The render "edit" makes complete sense, its going to render that new form again. But what in the world is going on with `redirect_to(@book)`? What exactly is that going to render and how is a book object going to be redirected to? BTW, the book model has columns, Name, author, pages etc...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[redirect_to documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html)

> redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {}) Redirects the
>   browser to the target specified in options.
>   **Record** - The URL will be generated by calling
>   url_for with the options, which will reference a named URL for that
>   record.

So when one does `redirect_to(@book)` `@book` is a specific record with an `id` .

Thus, the associated records (in this case @book) **show** method is used as a template.

In addition to above, if you look at the `routes.rb` file which defines these paths you will notice

```
resources :books
```

Now this route is essentially translated as (you can see by running `rake routes`)

```
    books GET    /books(.:format)                   books#index
          POST   /books(.:format)                   books#create
 new_book GET    /books/new(.:format)               books#new
edit_book GET    /books/:id/edit(.:format)          books#edit
     book GET    /books/:id(.:format)               books#show
          PUT    /books/:id(.:format)               books#update
          DELETE /books/:id(.:format)               books#destroy
```

Notice the `book GET /books/:id books#show` - which gets matched when you do `redirect_to(@book)`

Answer (score 0):

It'll redirect to a book, for example "/books/65"

Comment: Lets say URL is /myapp/books/65 and the 65 gets passed through the params hash, what exactly is redirect_to(@book). This will take me to a page that shows details for book 65? Also, what about a params hash that has params[:book].. What is this? A form post method that contains all the records?