# Rails redirect_to is going to index page instead of show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I'm building a model without a table.  The intent is that I want it to behave like a model, but I only ever need one instance of the object.  The core of my model class looks like

```
class JobScheduler
  include ActiveModel::Model

  @@job_scheduler_instance = nil

  attr_accessor :timeout

  # Public: Override the ActiveModel initialize method to set the
  # job_scheduler_instance.  This is used by the JobScheduler::new
  # method to determine whether to create a new job_scheduler instance
  # or return the existing one.
  def initialize(*args)
    super

    Rails.logger.warn "JobScheduler instance already exists!" if @@job_scheduler_instance
    @@job_scheduler_instance ||= self
  end

  def id
    '1'
  end

  def to_param
    '1'
  end

  class << self
    # Public: Modify the ::new method to return the job_scheduler_instance
    # determined during #initialize.  This is designed to ensure that
    # only one scheduler instance is created at a time.
    #
    # Returns a JobScheduler instance.
    def new(*args)
      super
      @@job_scheduler_instance
    end

    # Public: Returns the job scheduler instance (if defined).
    #
    # Returns a JobScheduler instance.
    def all
      Array(@@job_scheduler_instance)
    end

    def find(*args)
      @@job_scheduler_instance
    end

  end
end
```

The issue I'm having is that any references to `redirect_to @job_scheduler` seem to be going to the '/job_schedulers' route, aka the `index` action.  I'm not clear why that's happening or what I can do to fix it.

Controller:

```
# GET /job_schedulers/new
def new
  @job_scheduler = JobScheduler.new
  redirect_to @job_scheduler
end
```

But when I visit `/job_schedulers/new`, I get the error: `No route matches [GET] "/job_schedulers"` but I would have expected it to try to point to the route `/job_schedulers/1`.

Now, when I change the controller to

```
# GET /job_schedulers/new
def new
  @job_scheduler = JobScheduler.new
  redirect_to job_schduler_url(@job_scheduler)
end
```

I do get the expected result of it redirecting to `/job_schedulers/1`, but I don't understand why this works but the above does not.

Routes:

```
  resources :job_schedulers, only: [:show, :new, :create, :destroy]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks...

Comment: can you show your routes?

Comment: Updated with routes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `redirect_to` uses the `id` of the object, when using the syntax:

```
redirect_to @instance_variable
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179050/confusion-about-passing-instance-variables-to-redirect-to-method-as-seen-in-rai) for more info.

Because you have only instantiated the object it does not have an `id`. Saving the object before calling `redirect_to` will create a record of the object with an `id` and should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I modified the model to include def id; '1'; end so it would have an id, but I'm still  having the same issue.

Comment: @SterlingParamore Ah. I tested it myself and managed to reproduce the problem. I used `@model.create` instead of `@model.new` to fix it. Perhaps there is something else missing, other than `id`, when not persisting the object.

Comment: I'm sure I'm just missing something else, I just don't know what that is.