# How is this sent to the Show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect

I am new to ruby on rails and i want to understand how this piece of code redirect to the show action thanks :

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(params[:article])
  @article.save

  redirect_to @article
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Confusion about passing instance variables to redirect\_to method. As seen in Rails Guides](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179050/confusion-about-passing-instance-variables-to-redirect-to-method-as-seen-in-rai)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define your routes using the Rails convention of defining RESTful routes i.e. `resources :articles` in your `routes.rb` file, then `redirect_to @article` will take you to the `show` page of this particular `@article` instance. Rails is doing the underlying magic here.

When you write `resources :articles` in your `routes.rb` file, Rails is generating these routes for you automatically:

```
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
    articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
             POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
 new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
     article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
             PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
```

So you have this particular route which is mapped to `articles` controller's `show` action:

```
article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
```

This route is matched when you do: `redirect_to @article` and that is why it's taking you to the `show` page of this `@article`.

To know more about how RESTful routes works, see [this Rails tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web)

Comment: you give great answers K M!

Comment: @HolyMoly Thank you. If you really think so, then you should consider upvoting the answers you like and find helpful.

Comment: oh ii thought i did, i just upvoted another one of your answers around the same time i left this comment ;)

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have the following route:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
```

In order to redirect to the `show` action of a specific article, you need to end up with a string of the form '/articles/:id', and there are several levels of syntastic sugar to accomplish this:

```
redirect_to @article
redirect_to article_path(@article)
redirect_to article_path(@article.id)
```

You could also explicitly specify the path, or even the full URL:

```
redirect_to "/articles/#{@article.id}"
redirect_to "http://myapp.com/articles/#{@article.id}"
```

although I wouldn't recommend that.

See the [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html) for more ways of using `redirect_to`

Comment: If i'm not I think also redirect_to uses get by default so that already reduces the possible routes then realises that an article has an id and therefore it matches to the show action.

Comment: Really like the way you mention the different levels of syntactic sugar (code block 2) most people don't explain it this way for beginners and imho beginners should only use the second syntax (in code block 2) and when confident be introduced to use this syntactic sugar. (But it's nice to know syntax one (code block 2) it's there for when you become a pro :) )

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14179149/7159163 which I found useful.

Answer (score 1):

> I am new to ruby on rails

To understand how it works, you need to understand the nature of Ruby, rather than Rails.

---

[**OOP**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)

Because Rails is built on top of Ruby, it's an exponent of the *object orientated programming* pattern  - the idea that every element of your application should be geared towards the creation & manipulation of *objects*:

[image]

Although the answer to your question lies in the *Rails* application of this methodology, its understanding begins in how *Ruby* gets it to work.

In order to have a truly object orientated experience, Ruby builds [*classes*](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/tut_classes.html) which are available in memory to manipulate & utilize. These classes are invoked, and have a series of [*methods*](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_methods.htm) which you can use to interact with them.

In the sense of Rails (I'm not super experienced with Ruby), these methods come in two forms:

> - *Class* methods (`def self.x`)
> - *Instance* methods (`def x`)

These work to give you the ability to *call* these methods to manipulate your object as you see fit. For example, if you were creating a game with aliens, you could have `@alien.is_visible?`

This is the underline structure which Ruby gives us.

---

**Rails**

Because *Rails* is built on top of *Ruby* (Ruby being the language, Rails being the framework), your answer lies in how Rails manipulates the objects you create.

To understand it properly, you need to know that Rails is an [MVC (**M**odel **V**iew **C**ontroller)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) framework:

[image]

As you can see, Rails builds your objects in your *Models*. This is why you can call `@article = Article.find x`.

Thus, when you ask how `redirect_to @article` works, you need to remember that Rails builds its objects in a certain way (IE with a series of *base* methods - inherited from `ActiveRecord::Base`).

These methods give each model *object* a certain structure, which Rails can use within its helpers. This is the case with `redirect_to`:

```
          Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                  Controller#Action

        articles GET      /articles(.:format)          articles#index
                 POST     /articles(.:format)          articles#create
     new_article GET      /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
    edit_article GET      /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
         article GET      /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
                 PATCH    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
                 PUT      /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
                 DELETE   /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
```

Rails expects its objects to conform to a certain structure, backed up by [CRUD / RESTful routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web):

[image]

Thus, if you have `@article` (which is to conform with Rails' model structure, and you have the routes set up as below):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :articles
```

[image]

Rails will be able to take your *instance* of the `Article` object, and use it to populate the `redirect_to` route.

--

This is how Rails populates many of its helper methods, including `form_for` and `render`. It's intelligent guessing, based on the conventions which govern the framework.

It's why Rails programmers are often eager to point out how "Railsy" their code is.