# Pass an instance object as the parameter into redirect_to method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning Ruby on Rails and I am not sure what my understanding is correct.

I just define a method in controller:

```
def create
  page_params = params.require(:page).permit(:title, :body, :slug)
  @page = Page.new(page_params)
  #render text: @page.to_json
  @page.save
  redirect_to @page
end
```

First, I store the form data into an instance variable @page, and I use `render text: @page.to_json` to see the content in the object, which contains:

```
{
  id: null,
  title: "This a new post",
  body: "This a new post This a new post",
  slug: "This a new post",
  created_at: null,
  updated_at: null
}
```

The first question is that it seems that there is no url information in the @page, how does Rails know the path by @page?

The other question is when I pass this instance object into redirect_to, does it an syntactic sugar of `redirect_to url_for(@page)`?

Comment: 2. Yes. 1. See answer on Q2 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routes are defined in the `routes.rb` file. For more details, refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html.
To see the routes of your application there are two ways i.e.

```
a. Execute rake:routes in your terminal.
b. Open localhost:3000/anywrongroute
```

It will display all the routes in your application.

2. Yes

Answer (score 0):

I found that @Horse Voice has asked a similar question before and @Nishant has provided a good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179050/confusion-about-passing-instance-variables-to-redirect-to-method-as-seen-in-rai/14179149#14179149).